# Google sheet as forms

Tags: forms, google-sheets

I had to resort to Google sheet as forms to be filled in by customers. For submission I use App scripts. it works well. Only thing is that the sheet can be modified by multiple persons. For example, if a person A is not finished filling in this form, person B can enter and modify it the same form. Is there a way to make the sheet always loads a fresh copy?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know this isn't possible.

"Google Docs allows multiple users to edit the same document simultaneously. There is only one version of the document, the current version."

Would it be possible to collect the information via google forms? You could then run the scripts when the information is transferred into the sheet.

Comment: I need interactive form- dynamic drop down lists etc. So i cannot use forms.

Comment: Yeah figured there would be a reason. Hope you find a work around!